# Rails ActionMailer add a delay for few milliseconds before sending an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delay, actionmailer

Is there a way to achieve above at a single place, as we have lot of places to send email and can't change email sending calls to add a delay through out the application code base.

We just want to make sure that not more than X emails are being sent in 1 second.

We are using rails 2.3.5.

Thanks

**EDIT**

We are using Amazon SES for sending emails. Initially they allow 1 email per second. What happens if we send more than one emails per seconds. Would SES queue them or throw some exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your mail sending logic async by using a job queue, for example [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)
2. Have a job processor that takes jobs from the queue and processes them, as such you can control the sending interval from the processor logic

Comment: Thanks, clyfe. Well, this is the one way to do it. Is there a way to override the Actionmailer's `send` method to add a delay or some other way? Thanks again.

Comment: No, there isn't. You will either block your req-res cycle (bad), either spin off a thread delay in it and send, but this second does not solve the issue, will have the same throughput. So no!

Comment: So, the only way is to use some job queue, or add a delay manually before the email sending code?

Comment: From your app code point of view yes, that's the only way. It may be possible to use a mail server and send via SMTP, and configure the mail server to queue the emails so as to send them delayed and evenly spread, but I am not experienced here, maybe ask on serverfault.com

Comment: Just to clarify, we were sending emails using Gmail SMTP. Now we are moving to Amazon SES. We just want to make sure that not more than 5 emails are being sent from our account. Our application is hosted on multiple server (standalone instances), we need to consider the email delivery from all servers collectively.

Comment: Do the queue thing. All servers would push to the same queue, this way the collective consideration would be dealt with, and the throttling would be done at the other end of the queue.

Comment: Im having the same issue. I already implemented delayed_job but Im not sure that its working. Doo you guys comfimrs that this method is working with you?